# Subset a list of np.array based on another array

Tags: python-2.7, subset

I have a list of arrays, for example as below:

```
L = [[1, 2, 3], [3,4,5], [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

I also have another variable which shows which of these group together, for example:

```
group = [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

I want to split `L` based on `group` so the result would be:

```
L_split = [[[1,2,3], [3,4,5]], 
           [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]]
```

However it needs to be done in such a way so that the number of unique values in group can change. For example, group could equally be

```
group = [0, 0, 1, 2]
```

or

```
group = [3, 2, 1, 0]
```

I think there may be a solution that involves sets in some way, but this is something I have yet to get my head around. Any advice for a solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a zip command, and a pre-sized list.

```
clusterZip = zip(group, L)
clusterSubset = [list() for _ in xrange(np.unique(group))]
for row in clusterZip:
    c = row[0]
    v = row[1]
    clusterSubset[c].append(v)
```